# Verifying if $F$ such that $F(1,0) = (2,5)$ and $F(0,1) = (3,4)$ is an automorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What I did:

$$(x,y) = x(1,0) + y(0,1)\implies\\F(x,y) = xF(1,0) + yF(0,1)\implies\\F(x,y) = x(2,5) + y(3,4) = (2x+3y, 5x+4y)$$

I need to verify if $G = I + F$ is na automorphism. So:

$$G = I + F = (x,y)+(2x+3y, 5x+4y) = (3x+3y, 5x+5y)$$

which has infinite solutions to $(3x+3y, 5x+5y) = (0,0)$, so $\mbox{ker(G)}$ is not only spanned by $(0,0)$, therefore the function is not bijective, therefore not na automorphism. Is my solution rigth?

Comment: Do you mean $F$ or $I+F$, those are different questions in your title and in your post.

Comment: @AdamHughes I mean $I+F$ sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the matrix for $I+F$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 3 \\ 5 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant is

$$\begin{vmatrix}3 & 3 \\5 & 5\end{vmatrix}=8-15=-7\ne 0$$

so that it is not invertible. In particular, your solution is incomplete as-is because you claim the kernel has infinitely many elements, but don't provide any (you should). Otherwise, the determinant is a very simple route if you don't want to compute the vectors (I provide as an alternative route if you find that more appealing.)